# I am testing a serial port device and want to know how can I understand the data?

Tags: usb, serial-port, hexadecimal

I have attached a device to my MacBook over USB-Serial device and I am trying to get the data in the SerialTools app (https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/serialtools/id611021963?mt=12).

My device is showing the following data : 
1.18
10.0
37.6
0.00
[image: Image of Data displayed on Device]

I am getting the following data on screen in Serial Tools app: 
<80><00><00><00><00><00><00><80><80><00><80><80><80><80><00><00><00><00><00><00><80><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00>

[image: Data displayed on computer]

I am in a fix. I tried hex to decimal, hex to ascii but not getting a clue.

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong baud rate.

Comment: You have garbage data.  `<80>` is likely suppose indicate the start of data, but the actual data, is just zeros.  Something wrong with your configuration.